# Bootstrap Remote tabs - load first tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [bootstrap-remote-data](https://github.com/thecodeassassin/bootstrap-remote-data) library to load data remotely since I have to load alot of data every tab.

My problem is that whenever my page is loaded, the first tab is not loaded when the page does; I need to click another tab and then get back to the first tab in order for it to load the first tab.

The above library contains a feature of "loadFirstTab:" variable which can be set to true or false, but no matter if the variable is true or false - it never loads the first tab.

Been trying to play with the JS class and my HTML for several hours and couldn't make it to work and load my first tab.

this is how my HTML looks like:

```
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" data-tab-url="tab1.php">Tab 1 - Never loaded on page load!</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" data-tab-url="tab2.php">">Tab2</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>

<div class="tab-content well">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active" style="min-height:300px">
<h3>Loading data, please wait..</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in" style="min-height:300px">
<h3>Loading data, please wait..</h3>
  </div>

<div id="tab3 class="tab-pane fade in" style="min-height:300px">
    <h3>Data for tab 3</h3>
      </div>

<div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade in" style="min-height:300px">
    <h3>Data for tab 4</h3>
      </div>
```

The JS class:

```
var $ = jQuery;
/*!
 *
 * Bootstrap remote data tabs plugin
 * Version 1.2.0
 *
 * Author: Stephen Hoogendijk (TheCodeAssassin)
 *
 * Licensed under the GPLV2 license.
 *
 * @returns {{hasLoadingMask: boolean, load: Function, _executeRemoteCall: Function}}
 * @constructor
 */

 var bootstrapRemoteTabSettings = {
   customLoadFn: function(isLoading) {
      var loader = $('.custom-loader');

      if (isLoading) {
        loader.show();
      } else {
        loader.hide();
      }
   },
   loadFirstTab: true
}

var hasLoadingMask = (jQuery().mask ? true : false),
    bootstrapVersion2 = (jQuery().typeahead ? true : false),

// hook the event based on the version of bootstrap
    tabShowEvent = (bootstrapVersion2 ? 'show' : 'show.bs.tab'),
    accordionShowEvent = (bootstrapVersion2 ? 'show' : 'show.bs.collapse'),
    defaultSettings = {
        customLoadFn: null,
        loadFirstTab: true
    },
    customSettings = $.extend({}, defaultSettings);



if (typeof bootstrapRemoteTabSettings != 'undefined') {
    customSettings = $.extend({}, bootstrapRemoteTabSettings);
}

$(function () {

    // try to navigate to the tab/accordion last given in the URL
    var hash = document.location.hash,
        firstTab;
    if (hash) {

        var realHash = hash.split('bs-tab-')[1],
            hasTab = $('[data-toggle=tab][href*=' + realHash + ']');
        if (hasTab) {
            hasTab.click();
        }

        var hasAccordion = $('[data-toggle=collapse][href=' + hash + ']');
        if (hasAccordion) {
            // for some reason we cannot execute the 'show' event for an accordion properly, so here's a workaround
            if (hasAccordion[0] != $('[data-toggle=collapse]:first')[0]) {
                hasAccordion.click();
            }
        }
    }

    firstTab = $('[data-toggle=tab]:first, [data-toggle=collapse]:first');

    if (!customSettings.loadFirstTab && !hasTab) {
        firstTab.click();
    }
});
var RemoteTabs = function (settings) {

    var obj = {
        hasLoadingMask: false,
        settings: settings,
        customLoadFn: settings.customLoadFn,

        /**
         *
         * @param tabEvent
         * @param hasLoadingMask
         */
        load: function (hasLoadingMask) {

            var me = this;

            me.hasLoadingMask = !!hasLoadingMask;

            // enable all remote data tabs
            $('[data-toggle=tab], [data-toggle=collapse]').each(function (k, obj) {
                var bsObj = $(obj),
                    bsDiv,
                    bsData,
                    bsCallback,
                    url,
                    simulateDelay,
                    alwaysRefresh,
                    hasOpenPanel = false,
                    originalObj,
                    showEvent,
                    hash;


                if (typeof bsObj != 'undefined') {

                    if (bsObj.attr('href')) {

                        hash = bsObj.attr('href').split('#')[1];
                        // prevent default hash actions
                        bsObj.on('click', function (e) {
                            $(this).tab('show');
                            window.location.hash = 'bs-tab-'+hash;
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        // check if the tab has a data-url property
                        if (bsObj.is('[data-tab-url]')) {
                            url = bsObj.attr('data-tab-url');
                            bsDiv = $('#' + hash);
                            bsData = bsObj.attr('data-tab-json') || [];
                            bsCallback = bsObj.attr('data-tab-callback') || null;
                            simulateDelay = bsObj.attr('data-tab-delay') || null;
                            alwaysRefresh = (bsObj.is('[data-tab-always-refresh]')
                            && bsObj.attr('data-tab-always-refresh') == 'true') || null;
                            originalObj = bsObj;
                            showEvent = (bsObj.attr('data-toggle') == 'tab' ? tabShowEvent : accordionShowEvent);

                            if (bsData.length > 0) {
                                try {
                                    bsData = $.parseJSON(bsData);
                                } catch (exc) {
                                    console.log('Invalid json passed to data-tab-json');
                                    console.log(exc);
                                }

                            }

                            if (showEvent == accordionShowEvent) {
                                hasOpenPanel = bsDiv.hasClass('in');
                                // when an accordion is triggered, make the div the triggered object instead of the link
                                if (bootstrapVersion2) {
                                    bsObj = bsObj.parent();
                                } else {
                                    bsObj = bsObj.parents('.panel');
                                }

                                // If there is a panel already opened, make sure the data url is fetched
                                if (hasOpenPanel) {
                                    me._triggerChange(null, url, bsData, bsCallback, bsObj, bsDiv, simulateDelay, alwaysRefresh, originalObj);
                                }
                            }

                            bsObj.on(showEvent, function (e) {
                                me._triggerChange(e, url, bsData, bsCallback, bsObj, bsDiv, simulateDelay, alwaysRefresh, originalObj);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        /**
         * Trigger the change
         *
         * @param e
         * @param url
         * @param bsData
         * @param bsCallback
         * @param bsObj
         * @param bsDiv
         * @param simulateDelay
         * @param alwaysRefresh
         * @param originalObj
         */
        _triggerChange: function (e, url, bsData, bsCallback, bsObj, bsDiv, simulateDelay, alwaysRefresh, originalObj) {
            var me = this;

            // change the hash of the location
            if (e) {
                if (typeof e.target.hash != 'undefined') {
                    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
                } else {
                    window.location.hash = originalObj.prop('hash');
                }
            }

            if ((!bsObj.hasClass("loaded") || alwaysRefresh) && !bsObj.hasClass('loading')) {

                if (me.customLoadFn) {
                    me.customLoadFn(me, true, bsDiv);
                }

                if (me.hasLoadingMask && !me.settings.custom) {
                    bsDiv.mask('Loading...');
                }
                bsObj.addClass('loading');

                // delay the json call if it has been given a value
                if (simulateDelay) {
                    clearTimeout(window.timer);
                    window.timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        me._executeRemoteCall(url, bsData, bsCallback, bsObj, bsDiv);
                    }, simulateDelay);
                } else {
                    me._executeRemoteCall(url, bsData, bsCallback, bsObj, bsDiv);
                }


            }
        },


        /**
         * Execute the remote call
         * @param url
         * @param customData
         * @param callbackFn
         * @param trigger
         * @param dataContainer
         * @private
         */
        _executeRemoteCall: function (url, customData, callbackFn, trigger, dataContainer) {
            var me = this;


            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: customData || [],
                success: function (data) {
                    trigger.removeClass('loading');

                    if (me.customLoadFn) {
                        me.customLoadFn(me, false, dataContainer);
                    }

                    if (me.hasLoadingMask) {
                        dataContainer.unmask();
                    }
                    if (data) {
                        if (typeof window[callbackFn] == 'function') {
                            window[callbackFn].call(null, data, trigger, dataContainer, customData);
                        }
                        if (!trigger.hasClass("loaded")) {
                            trigger.addClass("loaded");
                        }
                        dataContainer.html(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (data, status, error) {
                    dataContainer.html("An error occured while loading the data: " + error);
                    trigger.removeClass('loading');

                    if (me.customLoadFn) {
                        me.customLoadFn(me, false, dataContainer);
                    }

                    if (me.hasLoadingMask) {
                        dataContainer.unmask();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    obj.load(hasLoadingMask);

    return obj;
};

var remoteTabsPluginLoaded = new RemoteTabs(customSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a work around for this, i replaced this:

```
if (!customSettings.loadFirstTab && !hasTab) {
    firstTab.click();
}
```

with this:

```
if (customSettings.loadFirstTab && hasTab) {
    $(firstTab.attr('href')).load(firstTab.attr('data-tab-url'));
}
```

in:
`bootstrap-remote-tabs.js`

It seems to be doing the job and loading the first tab, but still, it doesn't feel right as it doesn't take into account the other things the plugin is doing such as Load Masking...

Answer (score -1):

Do you also init that in another js?

Make sure you load the script in the footer of your document or init it after document ready.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, add the following script to your html file

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tab1").load("tab1.php");
    });
</script>
```